# How to send user based or device based push notification alert from appstore console?

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

i've configured Push notification for IBM App store project. whenever new app in deploying and changing app to recommended, im getting push notification in the client app. what are all the other ways for sending push notification from appstore console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppCenter triggers push notification when there is an update to a version uploaded in the AppCenter server.

Comment: Is there anyway where manually we can trigger push notification only for particular device or user?@Vivin K

Comment: This is possible in IBM MFP server. Not in IBM Application Center